# Which file systems do support file locking

Tags: linux, filesystems

I want to use PPSS
[link text](http://code.google.com/p/ppss/)

According to the manual, PPSS should be used on a file system that supports file locking.

I assume that EXT3, EXT4, JFS, XFS, NTFS do support file locking, but I'm not sure.
FAT16, FAT32, EXT2 probably don't support file locking but I like to be sure of that too.

Comment: Who uses FAT anymore? If you're still using it, time to update. Most systems that support EXT2 also support locking; only specialty and very old systems wouldn't.

Comment: Most linux "live" distro's can be put on an usb-stick.
Most USB-sticks use the FAT fs by default and I wanted to be sure that PPSS runs on FAT/EXT2, as I plan on using it on such a live linux distro (Slax)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No filesystem supports locking at the physical level; all locking is done in the VFS. The ones to worry about are networked filesystems; NFS doesn't support locking unless the `nfslock` service is running, and other networked filesystems have their own way of handling (or not) locking.